# Angular Background Image - Keep Centred on width change

Tags: css, angular, background-image

I have angular image which I would like to keep in center when the browser width changes. ie the left and right of the image are cropped but image is focused. Currently its fixed top left corner.

Here is stackblitz
https://angular-template-tpjdhp.stackblitz.io

My code:

```
<div
  [style.background]="
    'url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b6/Santorin_%28GR%29%2C_Exomytis%2C_Vlychada_Beach_--_2017_--_2999_%28bw%29.jpg)'
  "
  class="home-custom-image"
></div>
```

Css

```
.home-custom-image {
  box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19), 0 6px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23);
  margin: 5px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  height: 469px;
  text-align: center;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size:  cover;
}
```

Comment: Here's your mistake: `[style.background]=...`. You are using the `background` _shorthand_ property, and that means all of the sub-properties that you do not also specify a value for _directly in there_, get set to their initial values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `[style.background-image]` instead of `[style.background]`

You are overwriting your `background-position` property when you use the shorthand like this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `[ngStyle]` and reduce your code for css as below

```
<div class="home-custom-image" [ngStyle]="{'background': 'url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b6/Santorin_%28GR%29%2C_Exomytis%2C_Vlychada_Beach_--_2017_--_2999_%28bw%29.jpg) center center / cover no-repeat'}">

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.home-custom-image {
  box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19), 0 6px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23);
  margin: 5px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  height: 469px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

And to make dymaic image you can use code as below

```
<div class="home-custom-image" [ngStyle]="{'background': 'url(' + imageUrl + ')  center center / cover no-repeat'}">
</div>
```